# skydrive upload for my WP in-app purchase receipts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive

Recently in my WP8 app, i enabled the in-app purchases where i am storing confirmation receipts in the isolated storage in user device. I wanted to store them in cloud, probably to my Skydrive account.

I am looking way to upload them into my Skydrive account, all the options i see are mostly related to uploading the data into user's skydrive account.

Any help in this regard? Is there any better way to get those receipts in any others ways (i do not have any external site or server to store them).

Comment: You want to store confirmation receipts from your customers to your Skydrive?

Comment: yes, that's the idea...

Comment: As a developer you don't have access to that storage on your customer's device.  Furthermore the receipt contains Personal Identification Information so unless you plan to encrypt everything on your Skydrive before you upload it having that information in plain text is a horrible idea.  Furthermore as the developer you already have access to some of the information through the store front, why, steal customer's receipt?  **There isn't a safe way to store files on cloud storage that doesn't release the authentication information to everyone.**

Comment: My intention is not to steal or any sort of...I am trying to save in-app purchase receipt for book keeping purposes and to make sure there is no tampering in the purchase and integrity of purchase. As you said already it does contains PII info, for which i am already encrypting it before saving it on to the disk. On the store side, i do have very little info about the purchases like count apart from that nothing much.

Comment: You have the purchase date, what they purchased, and a transaction id.  What more do you need.  It doesn't really matter those receipts are your customer's receipts not your receipts.  Even if you did encrypt everything I still wouldn't feel safe with having a receipt that existed outside of my control ( on somebody's random Skydrive account ).  As I said there also isn't a safe way to connect YOUR Skydrive account that would protect your account.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. To store anything on skydrive, you have to use the LiveConnect APIs using an authentication token that is only acquired after the user logs in using a Microsoft-specific page on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but requires to distribute your consent token together with your application, something that doesn't seem a good idea.

Here is how:

- Using your user account, consent to your application. You need at least the wl.skydrive_update and wl.offline_access scopes
- Save the returned consent token
- Every time your application needs to upload a file to SkyDrive, use your token to authenticate/authorize the request